# dd not performing as expected in Cygwin

Tags: windows, backup, cygwin, storage, dd

I am trying to backup an entire drive to an image file in Cygwin.

```
$ dd if=/dev/sdc of=/cygdrive/i/Storage$/backups/2018-09-18.img  conv=noerror,sync status=progress bs=1M
0+0 records in
0+0 records out
0 bytes copied, 0.00137615 s, 0.0 kB/s    

$ ../../listdrives.sh
major minor  #blocks  name   win-mounts

8     0 3907018584 sda
8     1      16384 sda1
8     2 3907000320 sda2
8    16  244198584 sdb
8    17     510976 sdb1
8    18     102400 sdb2
8    19      16384 sdb3
8    20  243567616 sdb4   C:\
8    32          0 sdc
8    33     409600 sdc1
8    34     510976 sdc2
8    35     131072 sdc3
8    36  248083517 sdc4   F:\
8    37     920576 sdc5
8    48          0 sdd
8    64   15314688 sde
8    65   15313664 sde1   G:\
8    80    7831552 sdf
8    81    7830528 sdf1   H:\
8    96 3903062016 sdg
8    97     131072 sdg1
8    98 3902929900 sdg2   I:\
```

It appears that `/dev/sdc` is empty, but then how would I backup the partition as well if I am getting the same results?

```
$ dd if=/dev/sdc4 of=/cygdrive/i/Storage$/backups/2018-09-18.img conv=noerror,sync status=progress bs=1M
0+0 records in
0+0 records out
0 bytes copied, 0.00144819 s, 0.0 kB/s
```

Comment: Is `sdc` a local disk or a network one ?  In addition the `$` has special meaning, so if the name is really  `Storage$` probably you need to escape it as `Storage\$`

Comment: `sdc` is a local disk. Will try with escaping.

Comment: Escaping wasn't the issue.

    `dd if=/dev/sdb of=/cygdrive/i/Storage$/backups/2018-09-18.img conv=noerror,sync status=progress bs=1M`
    `8567914496 bytes (8.6 GB, 8.0 GiB) copied, 57.0005 s, 150 MB/s`

Comment: so what is special about sdc and sdd ?

Comment: Nothing in particular. I wanted to backup `sdc`. It is an NVMe (PCI) if that makes any difference. `sdb` is C: on this system (also on an NVMe, albeit m.2).

Answer (score 0):

You can't access Windows drives that have drive letters assigned. You need to umount and detach them from Windows first, using DISKPART.exe, etc. Naturally, you can't do this to the system partition (Usually C:).

A better alternative is to use a shadow copy. See:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shadow_Copy
and:
[assign drive letters to VSS shadow copies](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/adioltean/2006/09/19/a-bit-of-black-magic-how-to-assign-drive-letters-to-vss-shadow-copies-on-windows-xp/)

Comment: I've been able to backup C: just fine without issue using dd in cygwin.